# Stop evalulate operator<<

Tags: c++, logging

I am trying to do a simple logging library only for my own. I know there exists several once, but I have not found any header-only, small and very "c++" like logging library which fits into my application.

Currently I have the following syntax:

```
logger << debug << "A debug message" << end; //debug and end is my custom manipulators
```

I have implemented all necessary operator<< and it works great, specially when it have backward compatibility with std::ostream. But I wonder, just for efficiency if it is a why to stop evaluate anything if some message should not be logged (after debug in the example)? Making everything after the severity manipulator "disappear"?

Just now do I have the following code in short:

```
template <typename Type>
Logger & Logger::operator<<(const Type & message)
{
    if(this->get_message_level() <= this->get_severity())
    {
        BOOST_FOREACH(std::ostream* stream, this->_sinks)
        {
            *stream << message;
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

Logger & Logger::operator<< (Logger & (*pf)(Logger&))
{
    return pf(*this);
}

Logger & debug(Logger& logger)
{
    logger.lock();
    logger.set_severity(7);
    //...
    return logger;
}

Logger & end(Logger& logger)
{
    logger << std::endl;
    logger.unlock();
    return logger;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be a bit tricky, depending on what compromizes you're willing to
accept in the syntax.  If you really want to support everything that
outputting to an `ostream` does, then the best you can do (as far as I
know) is a wrapper class, along the lines of:

```
class Logger
{
    std::ostream* myDest;
public:
    //  Appropriate constructors...
    template<typename T>
    Logger& operator<<( T const& obj )
    {
        if ( myDest != NULL )
            (*myDest) << obj;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

If logging is turned off (`Logger::myDest == NULL`), none of the
conversion code will execute, but you'll still evaluate each of the
arguments.  In my experience, this is not usually an issue, since most
of the arguments are either string literals or a simple variable, but
it's not a total 0 cost.  It also has the potential disadvantage that
the propagated type is *not* `std::ostream&` (although I've never found
this to be a problem in practice).

A somewhat tricker solution would be to use a macro along the lines of:

```
#define logger loggerInstance != NULL && (*loggerInstance)
```

This will still allow most of the actual uses with the same syntax
(because the `&&` operator has very low precedence), but could fail in
cases where someone has tried to be too clever, and embedded the logging
output in a more complicated expression.  In addition to not doing the
conversions, the arguments are not even evaluated if logging is turned
off.

Finally, if you accept a different syntax, you can write something like:

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
#define LOG(argList) logger << argList
#else
#define LOG(argList)
#endif
```

This requires the user to write `LOG("x = " << x)`, instead of `log <<
"x = " << x`, and requires recompiling if you want to turn logging on,
but it is the only solution I know which has absolute 0 cost if logging
is turned off.

In my experience, most applications can support the first solution; in a
very few cases, you might want to use the second; and I've never seen an
application where performance required the third.

Note that even with the first, you'll probably want to use a macro to
get the logger instance, in order to automatically insert `__FILE__` and
`__LINE__`, and that in the second, you'll probably still want to use a
wrapper class, in order to ensure a flush in the destructor; if the
application is multithreaded, you'll want the wrapper in all cases, in
order to make the entire sequence of output atomic.

Answer (score 4):

You could do something as simple as

```
extern "C" bool want_log;
#define LOG(Arg) do { if (want_log) \
   cout << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ ": " << Arg << endl; } while(0)
```

and use it as `LOG("x=" << x)`

Comment: I'm guessing that there are several different severities, and that "debug" is only one of them. So you might want something more like `LOG(logger, debug, "x=" << x)` and `#define LOG(LOGGER, SEVERITY, ARG) do { if(want_log_##SEVERITY) { (LOGGER) << (SEVERITY) << ARG << end; } while(0)`.

Comment: @SteveJessop If there are several severities, and you want to have 0 cost for the deactivated ones, you'll need several macros: `LOG_TRACE`, `LOG_WARNING`, etc.  And for anything other than 0 cost, there are better solutions.

Comment: Just wondering, but why the `extern "C"` on the boolean?  (I particularly wonder about its use on `bool`, because C and C++ define `bool` in radically different manners.)

Comment: I have the bad habit of declaring extern "C" all the names that I could `dlsym` (e.g. for plugins, etc). Perhaps it is useless here...

Comment: I also wonder about the advantages (or disadvantages) of using the `do { ... } while (0)` trick, as opposed to just `want_log && ...`.  The second allows things like `X::X() : member((LOG(...), initialValue)) ...`, which the `do { ... } while (0)` doesn't.

Comment: The `do{...}while(0)` trick is standard practice to be able to code something like `if (somecond) LOG("=" << x); else bar(x);`

Comment: @Basile: sure, but what James is pointing out is that his trick allows your example usage *and* his example usage. do/while only allows yours, not his, since your macro is not an expression.

Comment: @James: why does my macro not have 0 cost for the deactivated ones (in the case where they're deactivated by `want_log_debug` being a false compile-time constant)? Or rather, why does my macro have *more* cost than separate `LOG_TRACE` etc macros?

Comment: @SteveJessop I didn't consider `want_log_debug` to be a compile time constant.  If it is, you probably does have 0 cost.  I was leveraging off the original idea, in which the 0 cost would be achieved by redefining the macro to be empty.  The idea of using a C++ conditional with a compile time constant is a good one, and probably means that you don't need to break the syntax to obtain 0 cost; i.e. the second possibility that I mention in my answer can be made to have 0 cost as well.

Comment: @James: ah, understood. I was assuming that since for the macro to be defined empty you need not just a compile-time constant but a preprocessor-time constant, I was therefore entitled to allow myself a compile-time constant :-). I agree your option 2 has the same chance of optimization -- if the value is known at optimization time then the branch is determined and dead code removal applies. Otherwise, without changing the logging source at all, you can set the value of `want_log_X` at runtime. One (dubious) benefit of the empty macro -- the log message doesn't have to compile in release node.

Answer (score 0):

You could check for the severity in the `Logger & Logger::operator<< (Logger & (*pf)(Logger&))` operator and just return an "empty" logger that doesn't print anything in that case:

```
class EmptyLogger : public Logger {
  template <typename Type>
  Logger & Logger::operator<<(const Type & message)  { return *this; } 
};

EmptyLogger empty;  // Can be global/static, it won't cause any race conditions as it does nothing

Logger & Logger::operator<< (Logger & (*pf)(Logger&))
{
    if (logger.get_severity() < 5)  // Replace with a proper condition
      return empty;
    return pf(*this);  // What does pf() do? Aren't you returning reference to a temporary object?
}
```

Comment: But that would evaluate the arguments to be logged, even for the empty loader. A macro like in my answer don't evaluate them when logging is disabled.

Comment: That's correct. Without macros I doubt there's a way to stop evaluation of the arguments. However, I think that a smart compiler will actually remove those calls (because they are just `return *this`) when optimization is enabled.

Comment: @dark_charlie: only if the value of the "proper condition" is known at compile time. It's not clear to me whether logging level is determined at compile time, or by command-line arguments or whatnot. And of course evaluating the arguments must have no side-effects for it to be elided as an optimization, whereas Basile's answer skips the side-effects too when the logging isn't needed.